# How to get a property of an object that can be of different types

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on an Angular project. I have in my .ts file a variable called `planComponent` that is of type `PlanComponent | PlanComponentLabel`.
`PlanComponentLabel` object has a `name` property, but `PlanComponent` not necessary.

In my .html file, I have the following code:

```html
<p *ngIf="planComponent instanceof PlanComponentLabel" class='feature_block'>{{planComponent.name}}</p>
```

But I get the following error:

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'PlanComponent | PlanComponentLabel'.ngtsc (2339)
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

use **"?."**, example:

```
const a = component?.property;
```

here **a** have type:
SOME_TYPE|undefined

sintax "?." available in html & ts files after angular v9 (or little higher)

Answer (score 0):

first write a getter like so

```
get planComponentName(): string {
    return (<PlanComponentLabel>this.planComponent).name;
}
```

Then add this property in the html

```
<p *ngIf="planComponent instanceof PlanComponentLabel" class='feature_block'>{{planComponentName}}</p>
```